# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de los usuarios existentes en LDAP (Active Directory) y el estado de la cuenta en c#?

Tags: c#, directorioactivo, ldap

Necesito hacer un servicio en C# que consulte todos los usuarios que estén registrados en LDAP, todos los usuarios de red que esten allí registrados y el estado de cada una de esas cuentas para poder guardarlos en una Base de Datos.

Estuve buscando como poder recorrer todos los usuarios y me encontré este link https://www.luisllamas.es/consultar-usuarios-y-ordenadores-de-active-directory-con-c/
Allí explican como obtener los datos de las cuentas de usuario pero me surgen dos problemas.

1) Me trae efectivamente todas las cuentas de usuario, pero también las de administrador del servidor (que no es una cuenta de red) y una cuenta que no encuentro en el arbol de usuarios, es la cuenta `krbtgt`y `app`.

2) Leí que en la propiedad `userAccountControl` puedo tener el estado del usuario, pero me trae unos números que no sé qué sean dado que en la documentación no aparecen.
Por ejemplo, de cuentas activas me trae el 512, de otras que están activas también me trae el código 66048 y de las cuentas que ya mencioné que no sé cuales sean tienen los códigos 514 y 512 respectivamente.

A mi me interesa es saber que usuarios siguen activos y cuales no, así nada más, no me interesa saber las banderas de cambio de contraseña ni nada de de esas, solo saber si el usuario sigue activo o fue inactivado o eliminado del directorio activo.

Actualmente tengo este código para pruebas:

```cs
public List<string> ConsultarUsuarios()
{
            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
            List<string> d = new List<string>();
            using (var buscadorDirectorio = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"))
            {
                try
                {
                    SearchResult result;
                    SearchResultCollection iResult = buscadorDirectorio.FindAll();
                    if (iResult != null)
                    {
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < iResult.Count; counter++)
                        {
                            result = iResult[counter];
                            if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname"))
                            {
                                d.Add((String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]);                                
                            }
                            if (result.Properties.Contains("userAccountControl"))
                            {
                                d.Add(string.Concat("Estado: ",result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                    
                    d.Add("Error: ID = " + ex.GetHashCode() + " || Mensaje = " + ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            myLdapConnection.Dispose();
            return d;
}

private static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
{
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("directorio.local");
            ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://192.168.0.3";
            ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;            
            return ldapConnection;
}
```

Comment: ¿Entiendes lo que hace esta línea `DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("directorio.local");` ?

Comment: Es una función que uso para conectarme como tal al directorio Activo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buscando en la red encontré una tabla donde dicen a que se refiere cada valor que retorna el campo `userAccountControl`, les dejo dos link donde las pueden consultar:

[Link 1](https://jackstromberg.com/2013/01/useraccountcontrol-attributeflag-values/) - [Link 2](http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=16387)

Así que tomé los estado que para mi gusto indican que una cuenta está realmente activa e hice lo siguiente con mi código dejándolo de la siguiente forma:

```cs
 public List<userLADP> ConsultarUsuarios()
        {
            DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
            List<userLADP> d = new List<userLADP>();
            using (var buscadorDirectorio = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"))
            {
                try
                {
                    SearchResult result;
                    SearchResultCollection iResult = buscadorDirectorio.FindAll();
                    if (iResult != null)
                    {
                        for (int counter = 0; counter < iResult.Count; counter++)
                        {
                            userLADP user = new userLADP();
                            user.activo = false;
                            result = iResult[counter];
                            if (result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname"))
                            {
                                user.username = (String)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                            }                            
                            if (result.Properties.Contains("userAccountControl"))
                            {
                                user.state = (int)result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];
                                user.activo = ValidarEstadoActivoUsuario(user.state);
                            }
                            d.Add(user);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                    
                    string mensaje = "Error: ID = " + ex.GetHashCode() + " || Mensaje = " + ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
            myLdapConnection.Dispose();

            return d;
        }


        public bool ValidarEstadoActivoUsuario(int estado)
        {
            bool activo = false;

            if(estado == 512 || estado == 512 || estado == 66048 || estado == 262656 || estado == 8388608)
            {
                activo = true;
            }

            return activo;
        }

        public class userLADP
        {
            public string username { get; set; }
            public string someusername { get; set; }
            public int state { get; set; }
            public bool activo { get; set; }
        }
```